# RSpec - Best Way to Set Env Variable

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have class methods on a module and put a CONSTANT and call it on each class-level method

```
module Cryption
 module Crypt
  class << self
    OFF_ENCRYPT = ENV['IS_OFF']
    
    def encrypt
       OFF_ENCRYPT
    end

    def decrypt
       OFF_ENCRYPT
    end
  end
 end
end
```

That module created as a gem

[image]

That forces me to set environment variable before require the class

```
ENV["IS_OFF"] = "YES"
require "bundler/setup"
require "cryption"

Cryption::Crypt.encrypt
# result => "YES"
```

Is there the proper way set the environment variable on rspec,  I think I can't set the variable after require the module

`spec_helper.rb`

```
require "bundler/setup"
require "cryption"
```

`crypt_off_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe "YES" do
  before(:context) do
    ENV['IS_OFF'] = "YES"
  end
  it "encryption off" do
     expect(Cryption::Crypt.encrypt).to eq("YES")
  end
end
```

`crypt_on_spec.rb`

```
RSpec.describe "NO" do
  before(:context) do
    ENV['IS_OFF'] = "NO"
  end
  it "encryption off" do
     expect(Cryption::Crypt.encrypt).to eq("NO")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Env vars aren't really supposed to be changed at runtime. So, calling  `ENV['IS_OFF'] = "NO"` in your tests isn't really a good idea. The problem is, env vars are a global configuration, so if you change it from one test, the value will still be changed when you run the other test.

The easiest way to do this is probably [stub_const](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/mutating-constants), which will temporarily change the value of the constant, e.g. `stub_const "Cryption::Crypt", "OFF_ENCRYPT", "false"`. This is the best option, imo.

But for the sake of completeness, I can show you a way to actually change the environment variable from a specific test. First you would need to change the constant to a method, e.g. `def off_encrypt; ENV["OFF_ENCRYPT"]; end`. Either that or change the `encrypt/decrypt` methods to just read the env var directly, e.g. not from a constant.

Then, in your tests, you could do something like this:

```
around(:each) do |example|
  orig_value = ENV["OFF_ENCRYPT"]
  ENV["OFF_ENCRYPT"] = "true" # set the new value
  example.run
ensure
  ENV["OFF_ENCRYPT"] = orig_value
end
```

Again, I wouldn't really recommend this, but it is possible.

Comment: I hadn't even considered stubbing the constant, but it's definition a valid option for fixing an environment-driven test when the code itself can't (or maybe shouldn't) be changed. I'm glad you posted it as an option! However, I chose to stress a more TDD-driven approach rather than work around what I think is an anti-pattern and an underlying X/Y issue with the OP's test suite. I'm glad it gives other readers choices based on their specific situation, and appreciate the out-of-the-box thinking!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there really are situations where you have to change constants or even manipulate ENV like I've shown, for example if you're testing the configuration/interaction of an external library, but it's good that you show a more idiomatic approach when that's not strictly necessary

Comment: For the sake of completeness, another possible approach is using the climate_control gem, which essentially does this under the hood ... allows you to set ENV vars for the duration of blocks and sets them back when done.  Whether or not it's the best approach, of course, is a different question, but at least it lets you do it cleanly.

Answer (score 3):

### Mutating ENV: Generally an Anti-Pattern Easily Avoided with Some Minimal TDD Refactoring

ENV variables are inherited from Ruby's process environment at startup, and while you can change an ENV variable for the current process and any subprocesses at runtime, you're essentially working against the purpose of ENV variables by treating ENV variables as class or instance variables.

From a testing perspective, if you want to validate that a method or class does the right thing when ENV holds a particular value, you should design your *application* to create a copy of the ENV values you care about, and mutate those as needed. Alternatively, if you're testing whether specific values are properly picked up, you can fork a process and then change the value within the fork, which will not affect that parent process.

Here's what I'd recommend:

1. Refactor your class to use the ENV variable as a default.
2. Refactor your class to enable tests or runtime behavior to override the defaults.
3. Build tests that ensure ENV["ENCRYPTION_ENABLED"] (or whatever you want to name it) is valid, and can be easily modified within your tests or at runtime.

#### Example Refactoring and Some Test Skeletons

```rb
class Foo

  attr_accessor :encryption_enabled

  # set a default of true (or false if you prefer), or take an
  # optional keyword argument like +encryption_enabled: true+
  # when you initialize an instance of your class
  def initialize
    @encryption_enabled = ENV.fetch "ENCRYPTION_ENABLED", true
  end
end
```

This will pick up your existing environment value, but you now have an accessor where you can change it as needed for specific tests. For example:

```rb
Rspec.describe Foo
  describe "#encryption_enabled" do
    it "sets an instance variable based on ENV['ENCRYPTION_ENABLED']" do
      pending
    end

    it "defaults to 'true' if ENV['ENCRYPTION_ENABLED'] is unset" do
      pending
    end

    it "can be set to 'false' via its accessor" do
      subject.encryption_enabled = false
      expect(subject).to be_false
    end
  end
end
```

You could also update #new to take a keyword argument to override the default value, or perform other actions. The point is that ENV should provide *defaults* that don't change often, and your classes and methods should override them when necessary. This provides more flexibility for tests.

The only ENV-related tests you should really need are those that ensure that the ENV values are read and parsed correct, such as when they are unset, invalid, or whatever. Changing runtime behavior based on ENV variables is just an anti-pattern, so this is ripe for refactoring.

Comment: I try to use a class method instead of a constant, is it recommend? because I don't want to refactor the class it self

Comment: @itx I don't really understand your question here. Class methods have their place, but instance methods are generally safer (having a smaller scope) and more reliable behavior under various circumstances like auto-instantiation or running a test suite with a shared class object as the subject. You *can* create class variables such as `@@foo`, but I'd recommend against it on principle, and especially when you want to test behavior that can vary across instances.

Comment: I mean class-level method, like the `encrypt` and `decrypt` method, sorry I'm not sure the called the name. `def off_encrypt; ENV['OFF_ENCRYPT']; end` like Max told

Comment: @itx That's *not* a class method; it's an instance method. Nothing you're doing in your OP is turning anything into a class method, and Max's solution is about stubbing constants, not creating class methods.. If you don't understand the different between instance and class methods, you will need to open a separate question, as that is outside the scope of your original question.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs I think the confusion here is because they're using `class << self`, so yeah they are in fact class methods ... In any case your refactor approach only really works cleanly if they're using instances. I mean hypothetically one can use anonymous / higher level classes but that's pretty non-idiomatic in Ruby versus other more functional languages